# VIsual Basic- CommandType

Tags: sql, visual-studio, stored-procedures

I have a simple question:

What exactly does this piece of code do?

```
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
```

Thanks!

Comment: You are telling the cmd object what to expect. Check this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.commandtype?view=netframework-4.8).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because a simple look up to documentation will gives the answer